# How to get message after command in Telegram bot sdk Laravel?

Tags: laravel, sdk, bots, telegram

I have some issue with Telegram SDK! As you see in photo below, I ask to enter Some title after user enters /addnotification commmand, here user should enter some title of notification, but I can't get it, because update gives me last message , which was command /addnotification! Please, help if someone knows the answer!

```
public function handle()
{

    $telegram = new Api(Telegram::getAccessToken());
    $update = Telegram::getWebhookUpdates();
    $chat_id = $update->getMessage()->getChat()->getId();
    $text= $update->getMessage()->getText();

    
    $response = $telegram->sendMessage([
        'chat_id' => $chat_id,
        'text' => 'Пожалуйста введите событие или дело который вы хотели бы добавить.'
    ]);

    // $messageId = $response->getMessageId();


           $this->replyWithMessage(['text' => 'Поздравляем! Вы успешно добавили событие!!!']);
    $this->replyWithMessage(['text' => 'Название - ' . $text]);
   $this->replyWithMessage(['text' => 'Chat Id - ' . $chat_id]);



  //  $this->replyWithMessage(['text' => $messageId]);
    


}
```

}

[image]

Here after entering command user should enter some title and I want to get this title(message) , but update gives message which was command!

Answer (score 0):

You are asking the user to input a name for your notification in the same handler - your user has not done any input yet. The library you are using is providing handlers only for commands, you should handle regular messages anywhere else and use some state machine to indicate what input you are waiting from a user or use input syntax like `/addnotification *name*`. Personally, I could recommend you using this [library](https://github.com/westacks/telebot) for Laravel - it's documented better and has more features then irazasyed's one.